# MATLAB Unexpected Parentheses error

Tags: matlab, parentheses

I'm trying to enter this expression in MATLAB, and I get the error:

> Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

```
y = (exp(t./10)*sin(t.))./(t.^2 + 1)
```

I'm new to MATLAB and not quite sure what's going wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra dot inside `sin(t.)`.... `sin(t)`.  Also, it's a good idea to add a dot before the `*` operator if you want this to be element-wise, just like the rest of your operations:

```
y = (exp(t./10).*sin(t))./(t.^2 + 1)
```

To show that this works:

```
>> t = 0:10;
>> y = (exp(t./10).*sin(t))./(t.^2 + 1)

y =

  Columns 1 through 7

         0    0.4650    0.2221    0.0190   -0.0664   -0.0608   -0.0138

  Columns 8 through 11

    0.0265    0.0339    0.0124   -0.0146
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work! Why don't we need a . after the t inside sin(t), though?

Comment: Because you don't! Instead, can you tell me why you think we need it?  I don't see that you need it because it's simply improper syntax.  If you can enlighten me on why you think it should be there, I can explain how that thinking may or may not be correct.

Comment: @Ferreroire, the dot is associated with the mathematical operation, not the variable.  Hence .* is element-by-element-multiple, ./ is element-by-element-divide, and .^ is element-by-element-power.  As opposed to *, / and ^, i.e. without the dot, which are matrix operations. A dot is not required inside the brackets because a) it's invalid syntax, but b) the sine function automatically performs an element-by-element operation.  Note that you don't really need the dot inside the exp(t./10) operation because divide by 10 as a matrix operation is the same as an element-by-element divide by 10.